# React native , image picker , fetch , form data how to post request an image

Tags: laravel, react-native, fetch, fetch-api

Im trying to send an image to my back end but i receive it as a string [Object Object]

```
  const data = new FormData();
          //file.uri returns "file:///...." on android and base64 on web 
          data.append('pic', { filename : 'dd.jpeg' , uri : file.uri, type : 'image/jpeg'});
          let res = await fetch(
            'http://192.168.0.88:8000/api/review/new',
            {
              method: 'post',
              body: data,
            }
          );

          let responseJson = await res.json();
```

ON MY php BACK END

```
$request->file('pic') // returns null
$request->pic // returns [Object Object]
```

HEADERS (request)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryAmomk6ZVYcf1OVO0
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pic"

[object Object]
------WebKitFormBoundaryAmomk6ZVYcf1OVO0--
```

Comment: are you setting any headers?

Comment: Instead of `filename : 'dd.jpeg'` it should be `name : 'dd.jpeg'`

Comment: im not setting any headers.
solved it by doing this :
uri : Platform.OS === "android" ? file.uri : file.uri.replace("file://", "")

Answer (score -1):

solved by doing this :

```
data.append('pic', { filename : 'dd.jpeg' , uri : Platform.OS === "android" ? file.uri : file.uri.replace("file://", ""), type : 'image/jpeg'});
```